# Is Google Cloud Pub/Sub API Quotas defined anywhere

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

In the console they have quotas for Discovery, Administrative, Publish and Subscribe but I cannot find anywhere a definition of these four categories.

If I list subscriptions is that Discovery? If I get a subscription is that Discovery? If I create or delete topics or subscriptions is that Administrative?

thanks

Paul

edit: you can see the Pub/Sub dquota docs here but they do not answer this question.
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas

Comment: I assume you've looked at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs ? if you've looked at any particular link, it helps others narrow and respond to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Discovery" relates to calls on the [API Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/) related to Pub/Sub, so it is largely not relevant for you. The [quotas documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas) mentions which operations are considered administrative: "The administrative operations consist of Get, List, Create, Delete, ModifyPushConfig, SetIamPolicy, GetIamPolicy, TestIamPermissions." Basically, any operation that isn't a publish, pull, ack, or push is an administrative operation.

Comment: The docs were edited by google to answer this question - so yes, the question is now answered